# GlassFish Error: JAX-RS EJB support is disabled

Tags: rest, glassfish, ejb, jersey

I am trying a simple app using Jersey JAX-RS + EJB 3.1 on GlassFish 3.1.2.2. All seemed to look pretty well with Jersey REST on GlassFish until I added EJB. When deploying the war file, I got this error.

`SEVERE: Error when configuring to use the EJB interceptor binding API. JAX-RS EJB support is disabled.`

Anyone who has encountered this before? Is there a configuration in GlassFish to fix this?

My EJB is a simple pojo with `@Singleton` and `@PostConstruct` annotation.

```
@Singleton
public class PurchaseBean {
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initializing PurchaseBean");
        setName("Purchase Singleton EJB");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: I have same problem. Any correct response? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like this is an Eclipse issue. I did the deployment using Eclipse with the GlassFish adapter. Restarting Eclipse solved it.

`Solution: Shutdown GlassFish, inside Eclipse go to Project->Clean(select project) and then start GlassFish again.`

I don't know why but it worked. :)

Comment: Same problem in a production system,son eclipse is not the problem :(

Comment: Same problem in NetBeans after deploying a Singleton EJB, and this solved it for me.

Comment: I also had this issue after deplying a Singleton EJB.  Using EE 7 in eclipse.

Comment: Actually this seems unrelated (or only indirectly related) to Singleton.  I can reproduce it by including certain Maven projects on my path that break the deploy to glassfish with a CDI deployment failure (I think caused by annotations in the jars?).  If I add, try and fail to deploy, remove, and then deploy again, I start receiving  the Jax-RS EJB integration errors again.  Cleaning the project and restarting glassfish resolves the issue.

Comment: Got this problem with Glassfish 3.1.2.2, too, when redeploying a .war using Jersey with EJBs. even **without Eclipse**. Undeploying and deploying again did not help, but **restarting Glassfish** did help.

Comment: IntelliJ user here. Restarting (not only redeploying) the glassfish project helps in 90%. However now, I had to **remove** the artifacts from the run configuration (**without** re-adding them afterwards. ide even says "warning, no artifacts selected"). no idea why this works but it does

Answer (score 0):

Working solution or the ones who run the Glassfish standalone: Restart the Glassfish. Glassfish version number 4.1.2